# Parameterize an xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a "complex" xml with some layouts inside. For example

```
LinearLayout
         LinearLayout
               TextView (title)
               ImageView
         LinearLayout
               TextView
               TextView
         LinearLayout
               TextView
               ImageView (icon)
```

In my application I need to reuse that block but changing some attributes (for example the title and icon) leaving the rest untouched.

Is posible to declare that parameters in the XML and change those attributes in the include point? Or I must make it programmatically at the onCreate/onResume/inflate of the view?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "Is posible to declare that parameters in the XML and change those attributes in the include point ?". I can't see your alternative

Comment: If is possible to set some kind of parameter and use it to define statically in the XML all the views or if I want to put that 5 times in my code I need to insert 5 includes and then access them programmatically and change the ImageView and TextView for each. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour Caroline,

you need to inflate a static xml and change programmaticaly the dynamic parts. Use ids to retrieve the widgets you want to modify and change their properties after inflating.

Also, you could consider using other layouts, nested linear layouts tends to be slower and less effective than a big relative layout for all components.

Regards,
 Stéphane